# Icon background color also changes button color. JQM 1.4.0

Tags: android, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I try to set the background color of an icon to green instead of the default light grey, but it also changes the background of the entire button. How can I prevent this? I only want the icon to change color.

jQuery Mobile 1.4.0

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar">
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#start" data-icon="home">Start</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-icon="check">Test</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear">Test2</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

CSS

```
.ui-icon-check
{
    background-color: #0f0 !important;
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
The **:after** keyword solved it! Due to this page beeing dynamic, I suppose it needed to apply the CSS after instead of "before" ?

Working CSS (thanks to **Omar**)

```
.ui-icon-check:after
{
     background-color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: We don't have enough information. I suspect that your icons are images so you may not be able to change their color. Of you are using an icon font you would need to change the `color' of that font.

Comment: Try pseudo selector `:after`. `.ui-icon-check:after`.

Comment: It's all standard jQuery Mobile. No custom icons. I try to change the **ui-icon-check** icon. I made a fiddle and it seems to work in 1.3, but I use version 1.4.0

Comment: @Omar :after made no difference

Comment: I can't debug it now, but try `ui-btn-icon-left`. Change left with icon position.

Comment: Can you provide more information ??

Comment: Left? But the icon-check has no direction...

Comment: @jessica I made a fiddle, but as you can see.. this works with 1.3.0 http://jsfiddle.net/ds4FB/

Comment: I removed all css but this, and now it works! Must have been something else

Comment: Oh it was the :after keyword that solved it!

Comment: it was what I've said in my first comment.

Comment: @Omar added cred to you, see above ;-)

Comment: I would be careful using !important - it disrupts the natural flow of CSS rules...

[see here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

Comment: @Baked In half you seem to be confused a little about the CSS :after attribute. :before and :after mean do something to the class   before or after the one identified by the CSS rule. So in your case set the background colour after the ui-icon-check class entity.

Comment: @PhillHealey, yes figured that out. Didn't know they existed when writing the question

Comment: If you have figured out your issue, you should mark it as answered or remove it.

Comment: @Ian Well if Omar writes his comment as an answer I will mark it as answered...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI icons are set colors, if you want to change the color, you'll need to use an image editing program to do so ( according to the source files of the jQuery mobile ui website ).

Another way around this would be to use a icon-based font such as font-awesome and use css like so:

```
.ui-icon-check{
   color:#FFF; /* Change to Desired Color Hex ( Or RGBA ) */
}
```

Which actually end up being

```
<span class='fa fa-check'/>
```

I do believe.

I would add an addition class

```
<span class='fa fa-check my_icon_class' />
```

and use

```
.my_icon_class{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Just to be safe and to not mess up the original implementation of the Font Awesome code.

Comment: No need for image editing, just change color using css